# What are the Necessary and sufficient conditions for concavity and convexity of a two variable function?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

For concavity and convexity is that the Hessian be  negative semidefinite and positive semidefinite 
But for strict concavity definiteness is only the sufficient condition not the necessary . What is the necessary condition for a two variable function to ensure strict concavity / convexity ?

Answer (score 2):

Your initial statement is wrong: the Hessian does not have to exist for the function to be concave or convex.  For example, $|x|$ is convex but does not have derivatives at $0$.

A necessary and sufficient condition for a convex/concave function to be strictly convex/concave is that its graph does not contain any line segment.

Comment: so the only way to do that is by checking it graphically? No other way?

Comment: You asked for a necessary and sufficient condition, I gave one.  How you check it is another matter: it may depend on how the function is defined.